# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error when context path is defined

Tags: java, spring-boot

Before everyone posts to say this is a dupe, I have read the other Q & As on this error and nothing I tried worked.  It was working at least at times last week.  Today, I am getting this error.  Following are my files:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>security</groupId>
 <artifactId>password-strength</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <url>http://www.xxxx.com</url>
 <name>Spring Security - ${project.artifactId}</name>

 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
        <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>9086</port>
                </httpConnector>
                <stopPort>9968</stopPort>
                <stopKey>jetty-stop</stopKey>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>
                <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <include>index.html</include>
                        <targetPath>docs/</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\integration\applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:property-placeholder />
 <context:spring-configured/>
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="security"/>

</beans>
```

src\main\security\web\Run.java:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Run {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Run.class, args);
  }

}
```

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\config\web-application-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/applicationContext.xml"/>
</beans>
```

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

src/main/security/web/UserRegistrationController.java:

```
package security.web;

import security.web.dto.UserRegistrationDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

 @ModelAttribute("user")
 public UserRegistrationDto userRegistrationDto() {
    return new UserRegistrationDto();
 }

 @GetMapping
 public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
    return "registration";
 }

 @PostMapping
 public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserRegistrationDto userDto,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    return "redirect:/registration?success";
 }

}
```

src\main\resources\templates\registration.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>

  <title>Registration</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:2em;"></i></h3>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Register</h2>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div th:if="${param.success}">
                            <div class="alert alert-info">
                                You've successfully registered with our awesome app!
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <form th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

                            <p class="error-message"
                               th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}"
                               th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('global')}"
                               th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>


                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user color-blue"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="firstName"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="First name"
                                           th:field="*{firstName}"/>
                                </div>
                                <p class="error-message"
                                   th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('firstName')}"
                                   th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user color-blue"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="lastName"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Last name"
                                           th:field="*{lastName}"/>
                                </div>
                                <p class="error-message"
                                   th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('lastName')}"
                                   th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                    <input id="email"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="E-mail"
                                           th:field="*{email}"/>
                                </div>
                                <p class="error-message"
                                   th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('email')}"
                                   th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmEmail')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                    <input id="confirmEmail"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="Confirm e-mail"
                                           th:field="*{confirmEmail}"/>
                                </div>
                                <p class="error-message"
                                   th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('confirmEmail')}"
                                   th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="password"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="password"
                                           type="password"
                                           th:field="*{password}"/>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="text-left"
                                    th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('password')}">
                                    <li th:each="message : ${error.split(',')}">
                                        <p class="error-message"
                                           th:text="${message}"></p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="confirmPassword"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           type="password"
                                           placeholder="Confirm password"
                                           th:field="*{confirmPassword}"/>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="text-left"
                                    th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('confirmPassword')}">
                                    <li th:each="message : ${error.split(',')}">
                                        <p class="error-message"
                                           th:text="${message}"></p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group"
                                 th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('terms')}? 'has-error':''">
                                <input id="terms"
                                       type="checkbox"
                                       th:field="*{terms}"/>
                                <label class="control-label" for="terms">
                                    I agree with the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a> for Registration.
                                </label>
                                <p class="error-message"
                                   th:each="error : ${#fields.errors('terms')}"
                                   th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Forgot password? <a href="/" th:href="@{/forgot-password}">Reset password</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js/}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I load:

```
http://localhost:9086/registration/
```

and get:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /registration/. Reason:

   Not Found
   Powered by Jetty://
```

Any ideas?  I have tried various things, read through several tutorials, tried diff things on various sites.  so far no luck.  Looks to me like it *should* be working, but...

**UPDATE:**

I reverted to a prior state in a few of my files (updated those files above).  I found the following is occurring: I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community edition, by the way.  When I build locally and run

```
mvn clean compile
```

the page does not load (no mapping found, the exception reported above).
However when I run Lifecycle\compile directly from under Maven Projects and set Jetty running via Plugins\jetty:run, the page loads successfully.  Further I may also need to mark root\src\main as the Sources Root in IntelliJ or unmark it, then mark it as such again, run the Lifecycle\compile again, then when starting Jetty, the page loads successfully.  Otherwise I get the mapping error.

This tells me that the success or failure is in some way dependent on how the project is built, ie, via what tool.  Also it seems to imply a tool state dependency versus a build issue as such.  This is frustrating and makes this a Heisenbug of sorts.  This is bad.

I am also adding the page I am talking about loading (registration.html) to the list of files in my OP.

Comment: Did you try if remove last / slash? just http://localhost:9086/registration

Comment: @JonathanJohx Yes I did, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Where you setting context-path?
e.g. application.properties?

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-context-path
```

In practice, saying about Spring Boot, after you set context-path, to access app through HTTP Request you must to prepend URL with context-path:

```
http://localhost:9086/my-context-path/registration
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning.  If no context path is defined, it is / . In my case then the service would be accessed via a GET to http://localhost:9086/registration   Since I am using jetty I could define a context in pom.xml under build\plugins\plugin\configuration\webapp\contextPath with contextPath being something like /apps.  Then my URL would be http://localhost:9086/apps/registration

Comment: Not really.  I have a procedure for clearing the issue up albeit temporarily, as described in my UPDATE.  That is an approach which helps the issue but does not actually solve the mystery.  Question remains: Why?  Why when I build and run one way does it fail to work and it does when I change it?